# Configure boot for dual-boot Windows - Debian

Tags: linux, windows, boot, debian, grub

on my second laptop I already have Debian installed but I want to do the same on my other laptop that I use for study but I need to keep Windows...

I know how to install all and how to set default boot on Windows or Debian.
But I wonder if it is possible to boot by default on Debian and to boot on Windows only if a special key is pressed (like w or fx) ?

Thank's for you're help

Steven

Comment: You can make 2 EFI boot entries and set Debian as the 1st option.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is installed first, the installer will detect it and set up grub to boot both Debian and Windows.  Simply change the order around if your grub config if you want to change the order of preference/default os.

If Debian is already installed, you'll need to install Windows, which will over write the MBR.  Then boot with a LiveCD/DVD of some sort, and chroot into your Debian system, and then you can re-install grub, which should detect teh new Windows bootloader and set it up dual boot.

Historical reference - 
The way we used to do it wtih NT4 and Win2k and LILO was to write LILO to the / partition NOT the MBR, strip off the first 512 bytes into a file using dd, put that file where Windows could see it, and change the Windows boot.ini to reference it.   Of course, each time you updated LILO you had to strip it off and move the file otherwise the system wouldn't boot...

Comment: Thank's for this good explanation but my question was to boot in a different OS if a key is pressed.